# Find position of item after sort?

Tags: java, sorting, collections

When adding a new item to the list, I normally sort it first using Collections.sort(list) so it appears in the correct spot. Is there an easy way to tell which position the newly-added item went to during this sort, or am I stuck doing a boring linear scan / home-rolled binary search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want all elements inserted in sort order, don't do add, sort, add, sort, add, sort, ...

That's about the slowest way of doing it.

To do an insert in the correct position (index), find that position using [`Collections.binarySearch()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch-java.util.List-T-), then call the [`add(int index, E element)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) to do the actual insert.

Comment: I think binarySearch() assumes the item has already been added; if it hasn't been added then it returns -1. I guess I could add the item, sort, and then use the binary search?

Comment: @user7085962 Try reading the javadoc again. It doesn't return -1. It's not a sequential search like `indexOf()`.

Comment: I literally just used it in my program and it returned -1

Comment: I didn't say it *couldn't* return -1. But if you actually **read the javadoc**, you'll find that any negative value is *also* the insert position.

Comment: Oh, huh, (-insertion point -1), so I guess I am really looking for -(result+1)

Comment: ...if the element doesn't already exist. Otherwise, you would use the positive value to insert it.